# Evitar reenvio de formulario en cake php

Tags: formularios, cakephp, controller, model-view-controller

explico el problema, el usuario llena el formulario y si presiona f5 o actualiza la pagina los datos que acaba de ingresar se vuelven a insertar exactamente iguales, una de las opciones seria validar que el id no se repite, pero en este caso no es valido ya que es un autoincrement.

Vista

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Need', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
    ?>
    <label class="lang" key="h1NeedForm">Aprovechemos el tiempo y comencemos</label>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('client', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Para que marca vamos a trabahar?",
            'key' => 'lblClient', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Dinos el nombre de tu empresa',
        'class' => 'validador txtClient lang', 'key' => 'txtClient'));
    echo $this->Form->input('need', array('label' => array('text' => "Escríbenos acerca de tu necesidad",
            'key' => 'lblNeed', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien la necesidad, '
        . 'es nuestro punto de partida para generar ideas quer fortalezcan la estrategia para resolverla.',
        'rows' => '4', 'class' => 'validador txtNeed lang', 'key' => 'txtNeed', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
    echo $this->Form->input('objective', array('label' => array('text' => "¿Cuál es el objetivo?",
            'key' => 'lblObjective', 'class' => 'lang'), 'placeholder' => 'Que se quiere alcanzar con la'
        . 'solución de la necesidad, ¿Adquirir usuario? ¿Mejorar ventas? ¿Posicionar la marca? ... entre otros.'
        . ' Agradecemos nos detalles muy bien el objetivo.', 'rows' => '4',
        'class' => 'validador txtObjective lang', 'key' => 'txtObjective', 'style' => 'resize: none;'));
    ?>
    <?php
    $options = array(
        'class' => 'lang',
        'label' => 'Enviar y continuar',
        'key' => 'btnFormNeed'
    );
    echo $this->Form->end($options);
    ?>
</div>
```

Controller

```
 public function home() {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        { 
             if(!empty($this->request->data))
             {
                $this->Flash->error(__("Emty"));
                $this->loadModel('Need');
                $this->Need->create();
                if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Need->save(array(
                            'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                        ));
                   //$this->request->data = array(); este código me lo sugirieron pero no hacia absolutamente nada 
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                 $this->Flash->error(__("No empty"));
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Sino post"));
        }
    }
```

Anteriormente tenia este codigo en el controller dentro la funcion home y siempre entraba por el post

```
//return false;
     // 
     /*unset($post);
     if($this->request->is('redirect')){
        $this->Flash->error(__("redirect"));
        return false;
     }
     else if($this->request->is('get')){
         $this->Flash->error(__("get"));
        return false;
     }
     else if($this->request->is('post')){
 $this->Flash->error(__("post")); //siempre entraba p
        return false; 
     }*/
     //
```

Model Need.php completo

```
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Need extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'client' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'need' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'objective' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'process' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
```

Routes.php

```
Router::connect('/Practica', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

[image: Imagen de info repetida, las "primeras" que aparecen fueron al llenar el formulario, y la segunda al actualizar pagina con f5]

[image: Cuando actualizo me pregunta esto]
Les voy a compartir las rutas, la función del controlador, el modelo, el formulario y una imagen de los datos repetidos en la base de datos.

En internet estuve averiguando y vi que en laravel pasaba lo mismo, que se reenviaba el formulario, pero para cake no encontre solucion pero se que debe haberla, estoy trabajando en la version 2.x pero para la semana que viene migrare mis datos a la 3.x

Gracias por toda la ayuda prestadas.

PD:adjunto ya todo el controlador y el deafult, aunque no creo que interfieran igual los voy a pegar por si sirven a dar respuesta a mi problema.

Pagecontroller.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Static content controller.
 *
 * This file will render views from views/pages/
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Static content controller
 *
 * Override this controller by placing a copy in controllers directory of an application
 *
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @link https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html
 */
class PagesController extends AppController {
    /**
     * This controller does not use a model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Flash', 'Js' => array('Jquery'));
    public $components = array('Flash', 'RequestHandler');
    public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }  
    public function prueba(){
        return "hola";
    }    
    public function home() {        
     //return false;
     // 
     /*unset($post);
     if($this->request->is('redirect')){
        $this->Flash->error(__("redirect"));
        return false;
     }
     else if($this->request->is('get')){
         $this->Flash->error(__("get"));
        return false;
     }
     else if($this->request->is('post')){
 $this->Flash->error(__("post"));
        return false;
     }*/
     // 
        //return false;
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
                          if(!empty($this->request->data))
             {
                $this->Flash->error(__("Emty"));
                $this->loadModel('Need');

                $this->Need->create();
                if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Need->save(array(
                            'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                        ));                    
                    return false;                                      
                }
            }
            else{
                 $this->Flash->error(__("No empty"));
            }
        }
        else {
 $this->Flash->error(__("Sino post"));
        }
    }
        public function fullClient() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //        $information = $this->data['Cliente']['informacio'];
            $client = $this->data['Client']['cliente'];
            $user = $this->data['Client']['usuario'];
            $password = $this->data['Client']['clave'];
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            //$posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_de_texto, $cadena_buscada, -20);
//        $this->Flash->error(__($hola));
            $this->loadModel('Client');
            $consult = $this->Client->find('count', array(
                'fields' => array('usuario'),
                'conditions' => array('usuario LIKE ' => $user)));
//            $aaa= $aaa['Client'];
            if ($consult == 0) {
                $this->Client->create();
                if ($this->Client->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Client->save(array(
                        'rol' => 'Cliente',
                        'clave' => $password
                    ));
                    $consult = $this->Client->find('all', array(
                        'fields' => array('usuario'),
                        'conditions' => array('usuario LIKE ' => $user)));
                    $id_client = $consult[0];
                    $this->loadModel('Need');
                    $data = array(
                        array('procesos_id' => 11112,
                            'clientes_id' => $id_client['Client']['usuario'],
                            'fecha' => date("Y/m/d")),
                    );
                    $this->Need->saveMany($data);
                    $this->Need->save();
                    //$this->loadModel('Need');
//                $this->Need->create();
//                $this->Need->save($data);
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Your informatio was save'));
                    return $this->request->data;
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Your informatio wasn`t save'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->success(__("El nombre de usuario que elgiste ya existe"));
            }
          }
    }
    public $uses = array();
    /**
     * Displays a view
     *
     * @return CakeResponse|null
     * @throws ForbiddenException When a directory traversal attempt.
     * @throws NotFoundException When the view file could not be found
     *   or MissingViewException in debug mode.
     */
    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();
        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        if (in_array('..', $path, true) || in_array('.', $path, true)) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Default.ctp

```
 <?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.View.Layouts
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.0.1076
 * @license       https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
$cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'Seadog Creative Labs');
$cakeVersion = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP %s', Configure::version());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<html oncontextmenu="return false"> -->
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
        <title>
            <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
            <?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?>
        </title>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon', '/favicon.ico', ['type' => 'image/ico']);
        echo $this->Html->meta(['name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'noindex']);
        echo $this->Html->meta(['name' => 'googlebot', 'content' => 'noindex']);
        echo $this->Html->meta(['http-equiv' => 'Pragma', 'content' => 'no-cache']);
        echo $this->Html->css('navigatePage');
        echo $this->Html->css('myStyle');
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min'); //problema
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-datepicker3'); //problema
//        echo $this->Html->css('reset.min');
//        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-formhelpers.min');
        echo $this->Html->css('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css');
        echo $this->Html->css('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css');
//        echo $this->Html->css('jquery.timepicker.min');
        echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="header">
                <div class="circle" style="cursor: default;">
                    <ul class="navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="active linkBrowserHome"><span></span></a> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="linkBrowserNeeds"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="linkBrowserStrategies"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="linkBrowserTools"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="linkBrowserExecution"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="linkBrowserResults"><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Html->image('cont-.png', array('alt' => '',
                            "width" => "100", "height" => "25", 'title' => 'h'));
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <li><a class="linkMenuHome" key="linkHome">Laboratorio estratégico</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuNeeds" key="linkNeeds">Descubrir necesidades</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuStrategies" key="linkStrategies">Definir estrategias</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuTools" key="linkTools">Herramientas</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuExecution" key="linkExecution">Ejecución</a></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuResults" key="linkResults">Resultados</a></li>
                                <li class=""></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuExplore lang" key="linkExplore">Explora resultados</a></li>
                                <li class=""></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuTeam lang" key="linkTeam">Equipo</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="linkMenuContact lang" key="linkContact">Contáctenos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <?php
                $here = $this->request->here(true);
                if (strpos($here, "?") !== false) {
                    $hola = explode('?', $here);
                    $hola[1] = str_replace('=', '', $hola[1]);
                    if (strpos($hola[1], 'publicidad') !== false) {
                        echo "publicidad";
                    } else if (strpos($hola[1], 'marca') !== false) {
                        echo "Marca";
                    } else if (strpos($hola[1], 'experiencia') !== false) {
                        echo "Experiencia de usuario";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "";
                }
                ?>
                <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
                <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
                                <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
                    <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-co" value="es"></span> Español'>Español</option>
                    <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="en"></span> English'>English</option>
                </select>
                <?php // echo $this->Html->script('jquery.timepicker.min'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-3.3.1'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?>
                <?php // echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap-datepicker.min'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('myScript'); ?>
                <?php // echo $this->Html->script('jquery.easing.min'); ?>
                <?php //echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap-formhelpers.min'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="form-inline row">

                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <br/>
                        <?php // echo $this->Html->link($cakeDescription, '#');    ?>
                        <ul id="menu" class="navlist">
                            <li class="contenedor">
                                Social network:
                            </li>
                            <li onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                                <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://facebook.com" title="Facebook" class="imagen"/>
                            </li>
                            <li onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                                <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://instagram.com" title="Instagram" class="imagen"/>
                            </li>
                            <li onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com', '_blank');" class="contenedor">
                                <img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://linkedin.com" title="Linkedin" class="imagen"/>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <br/>
                        <a  class="tip">
                            <label>
                                Designed by
                            </label>
                            <span class="by">
                                Leader:
                                Brand:
                                Communication:
                                Development:
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); //muestra consultas sql ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de regresar `false`, puedes hacer un `redirect` para que la petición regrese a ser `GET` y no se vuelva a enviar el formulario al recargar la página

```
public function home() {
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    { 
         if(!empty($this->request->data))
         {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Emty"));
            $this->loadModel('Need');
            $this->Need->create();
            if ($this->Need->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Need->save(array(
                        'date' => date("Y/m/d")
                    ));
               // Aquí redireccionas a la vista que estabas
               // Me imagino que pages home (?)
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
            }
        }
        else{
             $this->Flash->error(__("No empty"));
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->Flash->error(__("Sino post"));
    }
}
```

A esto se le llama [POST/REDIRECT/GET (PRG)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Por ahora me funciono.  pero así: ´return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'home'));´
Ya que no me estaba insertando en la bd, no se why.

Comment: @AndrésVélez te funcionó con `'action' => 'home', 'home'` o con `'action' => 'display', 'home'`?
PD: Lo siento por abandonarte en la otra pregunta, me ocupé en el trabajo XD

Comment: ´'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'home'´ con esa. PD:no te preocupes jeejejje me puse a buscar y di con el tema en concreto y así supe como formular la pregunta, es que en la anterior si sabia el problema, que se volvió a insertar la misma información, pero no sabia como hacerles entender que me pasaba. Y por cierto como haces para que se te sombree el código en comentario yo lo meto en medio de ´´y me queda como texto .

Comment: @AndrésVélez con backticks \`\`, puedes leer mas [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) y mucho mas en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: A es que yo había leído, pero no caí en cuenta que estaba usando los que van en dirección contraria  XD